# bcrypt, sequelize ERROR in ../node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

Getting the following errors while using `express`, `webpack`, `bcrypt`, `sequelize` node modules

```
(ERROR in ../node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' and ERROR in ../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore'
ERROR in ../node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in

ERROR in ../node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/my-work/react-ssr/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'

ERROR in ../node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/react-ssr/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'

ERROR in ../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore' in '/Users/yogesh/Documents/my-work/blogpost-example-react-ssr/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres'
```

Answer (score 2):

Its worked for me. i changed code in webpack.server.config.js yours may be webpack.config.js or webpack.server.js ...etc

.... webpack config...

```
..from...

entry:{...},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
  publicPath: '/',
  libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
},
target: 'node',
```

to

```
entry:{...},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
  publicPath: '/',
  libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
},
target: 'node',

externals: {
  express: 'express',
  bcrypt:'bcrypt',
  sequelize:'sequelize',
},
```

just add below code ( same for other modules )

```
externals: {
  express: 'express',
  bcrypt:'bcrypt',
  sequelize:'sequelize',
},
```

no need add

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

(we can avoid install one more module webpack-node-externals )